# How to set only color to fill_parent?

Tags: android, colors

I have this situation :

[image]

As you can see, my text and the background color are set to `wrap_content`, but I want what the bg color go to `fill_parent`. But I do want to affect only the color, not the text. This is my XML file for the text view:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:textColor="#c0413b"
        android:background="@color/bgcolor"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
```

When I set `android:layout_width` to `fill_parent` it actually works for the bg color, but when the text aligns to the left and I can't center it. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the TextView in a layout container like LinearLayout oder RelativeLayout. The parent layout container can be set in height and width to match_parent, don't use fill_parent anymore. And set the parent container to the wanted background color.